# Generate, this two div with classes (text-left, text-right) sequence in php

Tags: php

how i can generate, this two div with classes (text-left, text-right) sequence

```
<div class="blog-post text-left">
    <figure class="post-image">
        <img src="images/image.png" alt="Image">
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="blog-post text-right">
    <figure class="post-image">
        <img src="images/image.png" alt="Image">
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="blog-post text-left">
    <figure class="post-image">
        <img src="images/image.png" alt="Image">
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="blog-post text-right">
    <figure class="post-image">
        <img src="images/image.png" alt="Image">
    </figure>
</div>
```

etc...

Comment: Use a loop, change the class for each iteration. Edit your question and add the code you're currently using or what you've already tried.

Comment: thanks, how i can change class each iteration?

Comment: Should be a simple true/false that you can set during each pass, and then choose your class based on the status of that value.  As I said, post your code if you want more help

Comment: Show your javascript code so we can help you, Javascript is meant for DOM elements behaviour among other things

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this solution:

```
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $classes = array('text-left', 'text-right');

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $count = ++$count % count($classes);
        $class = $classes[$count];
    ?>
        <div class="blog-post <?php echo $class?>">
            <figure class="post-image">
                <img src="images/image.png" alt="Image">
            </figure>
        </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Indeed, but we expect some effort, like a search here and-or google.